# How can I reboot my VPS if it says "Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: linux, memory, vps

I'm having difficulty with memory usage on my VPS (CentOS) running PHP sites.

Until now I have been able to change things and reboot to try to analyze and fix things before the memory usage climbs again, but now when I type reboot it can't even do that.

**How can I reboot my VPS machine and get out of this catch-22?**

[image]

**5 minutes later**: now memory is almost totally **maxed out**, what could be causing this and how can I begin to fix it when the response time when logged in via SSH is so slow?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the virtual power button (the VPS control panel provided by your hosting company should have this capability).

Comment: In addition, I'd suggest running with at least a little bit of swap.  The Linux kernel becomes very perturbed on a system with 0 swap.

Comment: no swap is definently asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your VPS providers control panel may also have a feature which allows you to borrow additional ram for short periods of time to get out of tight spots like this.